# How to start realising secure multi party computation with blockchain

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I would like to realise some secure multi party algorithms with a blockchain. Simple stuff like: Bob is sending a value to alice, alice is adding 5 and at the end everyone will get the result...

I found alot of Blockchain frameworks but I think, that Hyperledger will be the best for my needs.

Could I use Hyperledger Composer or would Fabric be the besser choice? Composer is building up on Fabric? But Composer seems easyer to use? Can I visualise my blockchain anyhow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this thread -> [Chaincode using GO or Composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49110397/chaincode-using-go-or-composer) and this one -> [Does Composer needs an already built Fabric network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697397/does-composer-needs-an-already-built-fabric-network/48732606#48732606) for more information.

Hyperledger Fabric (the blockchain, which manages the endorsement/consensus of smart contracts) is designed to cater for your scenario and what gets written to the blockchain ledger, who needs to validate it etc by policy.  This intro -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/introduction/introduction.html should help you and this tutorial will compare Fabric and Composer as the means to develop your blockchain applications / smart contracts, especially the integration aspects that are needed by organisations -> https://blog.selman.org/2017/07/08/getting-started-with-blockchain-development/